# How to throw an Exception to the method caller inside a try catch body?

Tags: java, exception

I am not able to throw a custom exception from within a try block. The exception doesn't return back to the caller, instead jumps out of the try-catch block and executes the remaining statements (`return i;` statement in the code).
I know that I don't need the try-catch block for the function "exceptionTester" to run. However I'd like to know the reason for this behaviour. `exceptionTester(0)` returns 0 instead of the exception being thrown.

```
public class Test {

    public static int exceptionTester(int i) throws FAException{
        try {
            if (i==0) {
                throw new FAException("some status code", "some message", null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            int in = exceptionTester(0);
            System.out.println(in);

        } catch (FAException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}

public class FAException extends Exception {

    private String statusCode;

    public FAException(String statusCode, String message, Throwable cause){
        super(message,cause);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;  
    }
    public String getStatusCode() {
       return this.statusCode;
     }
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but your code sample: you should use "try .. catch(Exception)" with great care, only in special situations. Because by catching an exception, you as the developer promise that you can continue your execution normally after the catch block, whatever type of exception happened inside the try block. Good Java style code has very few try-catch blocks, and the majority of those rethrow a wrapped exception from the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing a `FAException` and you want to re-throw it. Either remove the `try-catch` entirely, or catch that specific exception (if you *insist*) like

```
public static int exceptionTester(int i) throws FAException{
    try {
        if (i==0) {
            throw new FAException("some status code", "some message", null);
        }
    } catch (FAException e) {
        throw e; // <-- re-throw it. 
    }
    return i;
}
```

It is also possible to throw a new `FAException` wrapping some other type of exception in the `catch`. Which might look like,

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new FAException("Status Code", "Original Message: " + e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Comment: I had the misconception that as soon as I throw the exception, the function returns back to the caller. I thought only the try-catch block in which the function was called would catch the exception .

Comment: @SaleelAli Glad I helped clear that up, consider also a `try - catch - finally` or a `try - finally`, the flow control allows you to manage external resources in a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

You are catching any exception that extends from `Exception`. `FAException` extends `Exception` so in your method `exceptionTester(int)` you are throwing `FAException` and immediatelly catching it. Since catch block does nothing, it continues in method processing. That's why return is reached.

If you want to catch any exception that can occur in method and rethrow it as your exception then:

```
public static int exceptionTester(int i) throws FAException{
    try {
        // some code that throws an exception 
        // e. g. dividing by zero, accessing fields of null object, ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FAException("Ooops", "Something went wrong", e);
    }
    return i;
}
```

If you want to throw an exception when some criteria is met:

```
public static int exceptionTester(int i) throws FAException {
    if (i == 0) {
        throw new FAException("IllegalArgument", "arg can not be 0", null);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because you are not rethrowing the caught exception in the main method.

Even if you do this:

```
try {
        if (i==0) {
            throw new FAException("some status code", "some message", null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        throw e; --> catching FAException and throwing it to the caller
        // 'e' is of type FAException (though you caught it as Exception)
    }
    return i;
}
```

It should work, and you won't even hit the "**return i**" statement.
Otherwise (if no re-throwing, the catch statement will handle the exception and not the caller).

Rest, I agree with the above answer.